# What will be rate-limit of two different applications with two valid API keys from same IP?

Tags: discussion, support, rate-limit, api-key

What will be the effective rate limit of two different applications with two valid API keys from the same IP address?

- Will it be whatever only one of the keys can use? So maximum 10k?
- Will rate-limit be 20k?
- When one key API key reached 10k, the other one will be used automatically? So total 20k?
- Will they have a separate 10k limit for each key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An **IP** has a request quota, an application key is used to determine that quota.

In answer to your question, 10k.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you will only be allowed 10,000 requests from an IP address no matter how many keys you use.